# KendoGrid Insert with JayData

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, jaydata

I have a kendo grid that is using JayData as the datasource. The grid has 3 dropdown controls in it. Everything works fine for editing. But when I try to do an insert, the fields with the drop down are not updated to the backing object.

As a desperate attempt, I added default values to the backing objects three corresponding fields. The dropdowns now populate the backing fields, but only if you click and change the selection.

Below is my code:

```
            <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1315/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/datajs-1.0.3.js"></script>
            <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydata.js"></script>
            <script src="http://include.jaydata.org/jaydatamodules/kendo.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript">

                var baseAssetMgmtURL = "http://localhost/AssetManagementAPI/odata/";
                var crudServiceComputerBaseURL = baseAssetMgmtURL + "Computers/";
                var computerTypes = [];
                var osTypes = [];
                var brandModelTypes = [];

                var init = 0;

                var computer = $data.define("computer", {
                    ComputerId: { type: Number, key: true },
                    AssetTag: Number,
                    BrandModel: String,
                    ComputerModelTypeId: { type: Number, defaultValue: init },
                    ComputerTypeId: { type: Number, defaultValue: init },
                    ComputerType: String,
                    PurchaseDate: Date,
                    OperatingSystemTypeId: { type: Number, defaultValue: init },
                    OperatingSystemType: String,
                    ComputerName: String,
                    Notes: String,
                    MHIPSConnection: Date,
                    RetiredDate: Date
                });

                var ds = computer.asKendoDataSource({
                    provider: 'oData',
                    url: crudServiceComputerBaseURL,
                    batch: false,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverPaging: false
                });

                var setGrid = function () {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: ds,
                        columns: [
                            { title: "AssetTag", field: "AssetTag", filterable: false },
                            {
                                title: "Brand Type", field: "ComputerModelTypeId", filterable: false,
                                editor: brandTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#= getModelType(ComputerModelTypeId) #"
                            },
                            {
                                title: "Computer Type", field: "ComputerTypeId", filterable: false,
                                editor: computerTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#= getComputerType(ComputerTypeId) #"
                            },
                            { title: "PurchaseDate", field: "PurchaseDate", filterable: false },
                            {
                                title: "OS Type", field: "OperatingSystemTypeId", filterable: false,
                                editor: osTypeDropDownEditor, template: "#= getOSType(OperatingSystemTypeId) #"
                            },
                            { title: "Name", field: "ComputerName", filterable: false },
                            { title: "Notes", field: "Notes", filterable: false },
                            { title: "MHIPSConnection", field: "MHIPSConnection", filterable: false },
                            { title: "Retired", field: "RetiredDate", filterable: false },
                            { command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;" }
                        ],
                        pageable: true,
                        sortable: false,
                        scrollable: false,
                        editable: "popup",
                        toolbar: ["create"]
                    });
                };

                function loadLookupTypes(url, cb) {
                    var container = [];
                    $.getJSON(url,
                        function (data) {
                            var lookUpTypeString = JSON.stringify(data.value);
                            container = JSON.parse(lookUpTypeString);
                            cb(container);
                        });

                    return container;
                };

                function getComputerType(typeId) {
                    for (var i = 0, length = computerTypes.length; i < length; i++) {
                        if (computerTypes[i].ComputerTypeId === typeId) {
                            return computerTypes[i].CompType;
                        }
                    }
                };

                function getOSType(typeId) {
                    for (var i = 0, length = osTypes.length; i < length; i++) {
                        if (osTypes[i].OperatingSystemTypeId === typeId) {
                            return osTypes[i].SystemType;
                        }
                    }
                };

                function getModelType(typeId) {
                    for (var i = 0, length = brandModelTypes.length; i < length; i++) {
                        if (brandModelTypes[i].ComputerModelTypeId === typeId) {
                            return brandModelTypes[i].BrandModel;
                        }
                    }
                };

                function computerTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                    $('<input name="ComputerTypeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "CompType",
                            dataValueField: "ComputerTypeId",
                            dataSource: computerTypes
                        });
                };

                function osTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                    $('<input name="OperatingSystemTypeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "SystemType",
                            dataValueField: "OperatingSystemTypeId",
                            dataSource: osTypes
                        });
                };

                function brandTypeDropDownEditor(container, options) {
                    $('<input name="ComputerModelTypeId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                        .appendTo(container)
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                            dataTextField: "BrandModel",
                            dataValueField: "ComputerModelTypeId",
                            dataSource: brandModelTypes
                        });
                };


                $(document).ready(function () {
                    loadLookupTypes(baseAssetMgmtURL + "ComputerTypes", function (data) {
                        computerTypes = data;
                    });

                    loadLookupTypes(baseAssetMgmtURL + "OperatingSystemTypes", function (data) {
                        osTypes = data;
                    });

                    loadLookupTypes(baseAssetMgmtURL + "ComputerModelTypes", function (data) {
                        brandModelTypes = data;
                    });

                    setGrid();
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: The only significant difference I see between your functions creating the DropDownList and the example in the KendoUI API docs is the 'data-bind' attribute. Have you tried it without adding that manually?

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? Try to catch exception if there is any with chrome

Comment: @HarperShelby - The dropdowns are in the Kendo Grid. Searching the internet, there didn't seem to be a native way to put them into the grid. Then we came across this workaround: http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/creating-a-drop-down-list-inside-a-kendo-ui-grid/

I will have to look at the example you are referencing (do you have the url?) and this article to see if your suggestion is doable

Comment: @HarperShelby - I removed the data-bind attribute, but I still got the same error.

Comment: @GaborDolla - Right now, it won't render in Chrome... I've only been testing in IE11. I'm going to go through and find out why... whatever issue it might be, it might also be the same root of the problem above